# It is possible to configure functions with subtype overloading?

Tags: postgresql, overloading

When using `CREATE TABLE` it is possible to declare `varchar(12)`,  `varchar(34)` or `varchar`  datatypes, and it will be different...

But when declaring a function, the "subtype" is ignored... No warning (!)... 
I see that to ignore is a good thing, the *function signature* is essential to manage [function overloading](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-overload.html), and "subtype signatures" will be a something chaotic to manage... But I not see in the Guide (also nothing at [typeconv-func](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-func.html)), no Guide's warning about it, no explanation.

So, in nowadays, 2018, after  all PostgreSQL v10+ enhancements... **Can I configure PostgreSQL to accept function overloading with subtypes?**

---

Concrete example

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( x  varchar(12), y varchar(34), z varchar );
\d foo
-- not ignored, as expected 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo( p_x varchar ) RETURNS text AS 
$f$ SELECT 'hello1' $f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo( p_x varchar(12) ) RETURNS text AS 
$f$ SELECT 'hello10' $f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

\df foo
                           List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types   |  Type  
--------+------+------------------+-----------------------+--------
 public | foo  | text             | p_x character varying | normal
 (1 row)
```

So it is impossible to declare `foo(x)` that not do the same tham `foo(z)`...

```
 SELECT pg_typeof(x),pg_typeof(y),pg_typeof(z) FROM foo;
 -- returns "character varying" for all
```

---

Of course, sometimes we can use `pg_typeof()`:

- With VARCHAR(s) is impossible to check `s`.
- With PostGIS's `geometry` is possible to check subtype (e.g. POINT  subtype). It is an *overload* workaround, but not "real *overload*".

---

**NOTE**: the parsing error with the commented `foo('abc')` will be solved with adequate "[orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set) overloading function set". In the example, with

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo( p_x text ) RETURNS text AS $f$ SELECT 'hello-text' 
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

the "automatic cast `abc` to text" solve the problem `select foo('abc')` is working.

Comment: So if we could overload "foo" as you show above, which one should this call? `foo('abc')`

Comment: Hi @RichardHuxton. Hum... Sorry, I not understand, I say that is *impossible* to overloas foo... It is because `SELECT pg_typeof(x)=pg_typeof(z)`  and  `'varchar(12)'::regtype='varchar'::regtype`.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: the question is: _if_ it was possible to overload functions as you want, then which version should be used with `foo('abc')`. The type of the constant `'abc'` fits both versions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This problem have a classic "solution" by PostgreSQL parser, it is an error when context  can't decide how to do automatic cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "subtype" is a **type modifier**, usually referred to as a typmod.

When you create a function with typmods in the signature, they are simply ignored. The [function catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-proc.html) only stores the base type IDs (unlike the [column catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html), which has an `atttypmod` field), so there's no way to differentiate two functions by typmod alone.

As far as I know, the only workaround is to create a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) (a user-defined type alias with the typmod built in). This allows your function to reference typmods without actually having to store them in `pg_proc`:

```
CREATE DOMAIN varchar12 AS varchar(12);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo( p_x varchar12 ) RETURNS text AS 
$f$ SELECT 'hello10'::text $f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

The motivation for this is usually to preserve the length constraint; your `varchar(12)` function will accept a 1000-character string without complaint.

But while domain types do allow you to overload your function, you still need to convert your values to the appropriate domain type in order to resolve the overload.

So it's probably of little practical use, unless you're willing to convert your table columns to use domains as well. (Defining your schema in terms of domains carries its own benefits though, assuming you pick more meaningful names than `varchar12`.)

Comment: About "So it's probably of little practical use", I agree that is an ugly syntax limitation to express *type modifiers*, but the basic intermediary solution is to use also the *default types* ... In your example, you can add `CREATE FUNCTION foo( p_x varchar ) RETURNS text AS...` and `CREATE FUNCTION foo( p_x text ) RETURNS text AS...`  as the "defaults".

Comment: By "little practical use", I just meant that you don't get any of the benefits of overloading, i.e. you can't just type `foo(x)` and let the planner resolve it, you always need to type `foo(x::varchar12)` to select the overload yourself. And if you always need to explicitly which overload you want, you may as well just call it `foo_varchar12(x)` and forget overloading altogether. The domain only simplifies things if `x` is already declared as `varchar12` in your table.

Comment: Seems good *overload* after `ALTER table foo add column w varchar12` (on my table with your domain)  and put back my `hello1` return for *foo(varchar)*... Real overload at `SELECT foo(x), foo(w) FROM foo` (the result is `hello1 | hello10`).

Comment: And, after `CREATE FUNCTION foo( p_x text ) RETURNS text AS $f$ SELECT 'hello-text' $f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;` the problem with friendly cast is solved (!), you can use `select foo(x), foo(w), foo('no-extra-syntax') from foo`.